# For nonempty set of reals bounded above, show its supremum is in the closure.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Please provide your evaluation of my sketch of the proof for the following problem from scale 1-5 on clarity, conciseness, and validity. Thanks!!!

Let $B$ be a nonempty set of real numbers bounded above. Let $s=$ sup $B$. Show $s$ is in the closure of $B$.

Sketch of the Proof:

> Suppose B is non-empty set of reals bounded above.
>   
> (3) Denote $s=$ sup $B$, and closure of B as $clB$
>   
> Suppose $s$ is not in $clB$.
>   
>  (1) The closure of B is the smallest closed set containting B.
>   
>  Since $s$ is not in $clB$ yet $clB$ is closed, $s$ cannot be a limit point of $clB$.
>   
>  (2) There is some $\epsilon$-nbhd $B_\epsilon(s)\cap(clB-\{s\})=\emptyset$.
>   
>  [4] By (1)&(2), no sequence from $B$ converges to $s$. Here, s could be in or not in $B$, so if it is in $B$, no sequence from $B-{s}$ converges to s.
>   
>  [5] By (3), $B$ must contain arbitrary close to $s$ regardless $s$ is in B or not.
>   
>  [4],[5] contradicts each other. QED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not concise at all, and there's a lot of redundancy. You've decided to go with a proof by contraction, which is fine:

> (1) Let $s = \sup B$ suppose $s \not\in \text{cl}(B)$.
>
> (2) Then there exists some $\epsilon >0$ such that $B(s,\epsilon) \cap
>  B = (s-\epsilon, s + \epsilon)\cap B = \emptyset$.
>
> (3) But by the very definition of $s$, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there
>   exists $y \in B$ such that $s - \epsilon < y \leq s$, therefore
>   contradicting (2).

Comment: Good answer. Helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can give a constructive proof.

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given. Then since $s = $ sup $B$, $s - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $B$. Hence for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, we can find an $x \in B$ with $s - \epsilon \lt x \le s$, else $s- \epsilon$ would be an upper bound. This says precisely that every neighborhood of $s$ contains some $x \in B$. Thus $s$ is a limit point of $B$, so s is in the closure of $B$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify, I think : from (2), you can say that $s-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is not in $clB$, so it's an upper bound of $clB$, therefore of $B$, which contradicts the minimality of $s$.

Comment: Yep. Good pt. Thanks. Helpful.